# Where should store refetch action be made in Flux app after authentication?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, flux

Suppose I have `Messages`, `LoginForm` components, `MessageStore` and `UserStore` (for keeping logged-in user info).

Anonymous users can view messages, favoriting and some other properties are available only for authenticated.

`LoginForm` is modal and when the user is logged-in I need to reload data from API for `MessageStore` with messages objects containing user's specific properties.

- I can digest `LOGIN_SUCCESS` in `MessageStore` (or each interested
  store) and fire refetch action inside the store.
- I can fire refetch action from the controller-view after `UserStore`
  changes. In this case I need to know all stores which should refetch
  after user logged-in.

What is the right way for doing this logic in flux application?

Answer (score 0):

In an app that I made that uses a login page and then fetches user-specific events from an API, this is the structure I used:

LoginPage (on submit) -> WebAPIUtils.login(email, password)
WebAPIUtils.login contacts API, upon response -> actions.receiveLogin(response)

receiveLogin then calls the dispatcher with an actionType of Login Response

My sessionStore listens for the dispatch, and in its switch statement for the case of Login Response it sets the user info in the store as well as sessionStorage. It then calls WebAPIUtils.getEvents()

WebAPIUtils.getEvents() then requests the user's events from the API, upon receipt it dispatches a receiveEvents action, which my main store listens for and updates the events in the store accordingly.

My components listen for changes in the main store, and when the events are updated after getEvents(), it triggers a re-render.

You can find the code for this here: https://github.com/hilary-L/react-cal-with-api